# negative entail symbol

Tags: symbols

I am looking for the **negative entail symbol** in latex where the positive is presented by `\models`. I tried `\nmodels` but it doesn't work (I want to have it in my beamer presentation file).

Comment: How about using the `cancel` package with `$\cancel{\models}$`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Standard LaTeX offers you `\models` and `\not\models`; using the `amssymb` package, you have `\vDash` and `\nvDash`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[ \Gamma\models A \]

\[ \Gamma\not\models A \]

\[ \Gamma\vDash A \]

\[ \Gamma\nvDash A \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `MnSymbols` package you have `\rightmodels` (or its synonym `\models`) and `\nrightmodels`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

\[ \Gamma\models A \]

\[ \Gamma\nrightmodels A \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `mathabx` package you have `\vDash` and `\nvDash`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\[ \Gamma\vDash A \]

\[ \Gamma\nvDash A \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Loading `MnSymbols` or `mathabx` some other symbols change.

Yet another option mentioned in a comment, would be to use the `cancel` package; this requires the use of `\mathbin` to recover the proper spacing around the symbol; here's an example showing a comparison between `\not\models` and a newly defined command using `\cancel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}

\newcommand\nmodels{\mathbin{\cancel{\models}}}

\begin{document}

\[ \Gamma\models A \]

\[ \Gamma\not\models A \]

\[ \Gamma\nmodels A \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about the implementation of the `cancel` package? I know your answer avoids the use of an extra package, is it a solution.

Comment: @azetina initially I didn't include this option bacause it involves not only `\cancel`, but also `\mathbin` and this seems to be "too much work" for an already defined symbol. However, you're right, it's another option so I've included it.

Comment: Thanks, very good answer. I used `\not\models` without any problem.

Comment: There's a marginal difference in using `\centernot\models` (from the [`centernot` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot)).